# How to display post tag on each post?

Tags: loop

I need to display it on each post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to display it on each post and only the first state if it has
> multiple states

I noticed there are `$categories = get_the_category();` and `echo esc_html($categories[0]->name);` in your code, which display the first category for the current post, but then note that [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) only returns results for the default/core `category` taxonomy.

For **custom taxonomies**, you should use [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) instead of `get_the_category()`. And just so you know, for tags, i.e. the default `post_tag` taxonomy, you can use [`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/).

**Working Examples**

1. Display the first `category` term for the current post:

   (you already have this in your code, but I included this just for completeness)

   ```php
   $categories = get_the_category();
   if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
       echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );
   }
   ```
2. Display the first `post_tag` term for the current post:

   ```php
   $tags = get_the_tags();
   if ( is_array( $tags ) && ! empty( $tags ) ) {
       echo esc_html( $tags[0]->name );
   }
   ```
3. Display the first `state` term for the current post:

   ```php
   $states = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'state' );
   if ( is_array( $states ) && ! empty( $states ) ) {
       echo esc_html( $states[0]->name );
   }
   ```

So as you could see, in the last example, I used `get_the_terms()` because `state` is a *custom taxonomy*.